# Chimpified MailChimp Shopify Connector

Tags: connect, shopify, mailchimp

I'm trying to connect a Shopify store to Chimpified (Mailchimp for Shopify). When the auth flow reaches this particular url: https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/authorize I get this warning.

"We're sorry, but something went wrong."

https://chimpified.com/auth/mailchimp/callback?code=

My client just gave me access to his Shopify store and I'm not able to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Did you try to follow the installation using the "master account" or the Shopify store owner account (which is the same)? @user3705249

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d0pbpov6tore2of/Screenshot%202014-09-19%2002.15.37.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because it's getting dropped by Shopify:

"The Mailchimp for Shopify app is going away on May 12. We recommend connecting your Mailchimp account to your Shopify store via a [third-party integration](https://mailchimp.com/help/shopify-workarounds/?_ga=2.17490737.962730907.1553781650-227774132.1552667292) or using a workaround. [Learn more about these changes](https://mailchimp.com/resources/shopify-integration-changes-and-workarounds/)"

Honestly, it's a real pain. I mean [Anielas.com](https://www.Anielas.com) site has been using Shopify/Mailchimp for years quite happily then that happens :(

Time to find a workaround me thinks ...

[Shopify Mailchimp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqniG.png)